# How do I print a UChar* var as a string from inside of gdb?

Tags: gdb, printing

I've been doing some work on an unfamiliar codebase that uses UChar* as strings. Uchars are defined as follows (at least according to gdb)

```
(gdb) ptype UChar
type = short unsigned int
```

However, when I try to print these in gdb, I just get the address. I can also index into the pointer and retrieve the values of each character.

Is there any way to print a variable of type UChar* from within gdb and get back a meaningful string?

Also, this is on OS X, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Just define this command in your .gdbinit and type uc varname (uc will likely work as a short form for the ucharprint command you define)

```
define ucharprint
echo "
set $c = (unsigned short*)$arg0
while ( *$c )
  if ( *$c > 0x7f )
    printf "[%x]", *$c
  else
    printf "%c", *$c
  end
  set $c++
end
echo "\n
end
```

You don't need to worry about endianness since each unsigned short in your UTF-16 UChar type holds a code point (or half surrogate) as a native binary integer.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to figure out what a UChar actually represents.  It is likely UTF-16 or UCS-2 (but BE or LE?).  Once you determine this, you want to provide (you can probably use existing code, such as [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)) a debug method to convert to UTF-8.  See http://www.skynet.ie/~caolan/TechTexts/GdbUnicodePrinting.html for details.

Comment: Note that current CVS versions of GDB integrate libiconv, so external hacks like above should no longer be necessary.

Comment: Employed Russian, care to post details as an answer?  I haven't seen that before.  Although I don't know how new the OS X gdb is.

Answer (score 0):

print is the same as x;
x/1s 0x1234 -- will print out that location in memory as a string, if you keep hitting carrage return, it will print the next line... etc...

If you want to monitor something continually, use display/ with the same format specifier as x (print).  "display/1s 0x1234" then every time you break via a breakpoint or a single step, you will see the information you configured print out .. updated etc...

Answer (score -1):

if it is an ascii string, you might try to tell gdb to reinterpret:

```
(gdb) print (char*) theUcharPtr
```

Comment: That probably won't work because UTF-16 has the high-byte null for common characters (i.e. ASCII), and C-strings are null-terminated.